# jQuery hide function doesn't work when using GET form

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys sorry for the title being a bit misleading it's a bit of tricky question.

So anyway I will first go over my current setup of my two web pages.

Basically I have this form on my homepage:

```
<form class="car-finder-container" method="GET" action="used-cars.php">
 <select name="make" class="form-control select-box">
  <option value="make-any">Make (Any)</option>
  <?php while($make = $makeFilter->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  {
  echo '
  <option value="'.$make["Make"].'">'.$make["Make"].'</option>
  ';
  } ?>
 </select>
</form>
```

The select element just loops a column of my SQL table to create the options, it's then using GET to select the same option that has been selected by the user on the used-cars.php page.

Here is the second page form code:

```
<form class="car-finder-container dflt-container">
 <select name="make" class="form-control select-box">
  <option value="make-any">Make (Any)</option>
                 <?php while($make = $makeFilter->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $selected = $make['Make'] == $_GET['make']?'selected="selected"':'';
    echo '
  <option '.$selected.' value="'.$make["Make"].'">'.$make["Make"].'</option>
        ';
  } ?>
 </select>
</form>
```

This part of the code is working fine it selects the option selected based on GET, I do have one issue though.

The form is used to filter what div's are shown on my page, all of the div's are in a list and the form simply uses jQuery to hide classes that don't have the same value.

This is the jQuery I am using:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.form-control').change(function(){
    var make = $(this).val();
    if(make != 'make-any'){
      $('.makes').hide();
      $('.'+make).show();
      } else {
        $('.makes').show();
        }
    });
  });</script>
```

The jQuery hides classes when the user selects an option, any div's that don't have the same class are hidden.

The issue I am having is that when the page loads div's are showing even if they don't match the value that the user selected on page one, the select element has the option the user selected on page one but all the values that don't match it aren't hidden.

Any idea why this might be happening?

Here is a live example so you can take a look: http://www.drivencarsales.co.uk/index.php

Simply pick a 'Make' and press 'Search cars' and you will notice that listed div's aren't hidden yet if you press the 'Make' tab you will notice that the 'Make' from page one is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are hiding the mismatched `<div>`s only when the value of `<select>` changes. Which does not occur by default when the page loads.

You can manually trigger a `change` event on the `<select>` using the [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger) method after page load to run your script as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.form-control').change(function(){
    var make = $(this).val();
    if(make != 'make-any'){
      $('.makes').hide();
      $('.'+make).show();
     } else {
       $('.makes').show();
    }
  });
  $('.form-control').trigger("change");
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the example, I have tried replacing my code with that onto the live site however when the page loads it shows nothing until a select option is selected, any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @DaleDoback does it have an option selected by default when the page loads? is there any content that matches the selected option..?

Comment: No however if the option has already been selected on page one why would it matter if there wasn't a default option for the select element?

Comment: I was just confirming you're not moving to second page with empty value.

Comment: No when the second page loads it has an option selected, if I selected BMW on the first page the second page loads with BMW.

Comment: Which exactly is the second page..? how do i go to second page..? steps? one possible issue is that there are many elements with class `form-control`, you might have different logic associated with them.

Comment: Also, i'm getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: MasterSlider is not defined`. This might be stopping script execution.